# Check if none of the multiple chars appears in string A?

Tags: python

I have a string, `A = "abcdef"`, and several chars `"a"`, `"f"` and `"m"`. I  want a condition to make sure none of the chars appears in `A`, i.e.,

```
if a not in A and f not in A and m not in A:
    # do something
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) are useful for this -- see the `isdisjoint()` method:

> Return True if the set has no elements in common with other. 
>   Sets are disjoint if and only if their intersection is the empty set.
>
> new in version 2.6.

```
>>> a = "abcde"
>>> b = "ace"
>>> c = "xyz"
>>> set(a).isdisjoint(set(b))
False
>>> set(a).isdisjoint(set(c))
True
```

**edit after comment**

sets are still you friend. If I'm following you better now, you want this (or something close to it):

We'll just set everything up as sets to begin with for clarity:

```
>>> a = set('abcde')
>>> b = set('ace')
>>> c = set('acx')
```

If all of the chars in your set of characters is in the string, this happens:

```
>>> a.intersection(b) == b
True
```

If any of those characters are *not* present in your string, this happens:

```
>>> a.intersection(c) == c
False
```

Closer to what you need?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this is not what I want ... in this example if c = "acx", I want an answer "True", becasue "x" is not in a, but isdisjoint gives an "false".

Comment: Sorry I missed your editing for so long. set intersection is definitely awesome for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
True in [i in 'abcdef' for i in 'afm']
```

gives True
and

```
True in [i in 'nopqrst' for i in 'afm']
```

gives False

Comment: More elegantly: `any(c in "SOMETHING" for c in "AFM")`.

Comment: I think for the same reason as I commented on bgporter's answer. This does work for me. But thanks anyway.